C++ darts project not sending score to display
I am trying to program an object oriented game of 501 darts in C++, I have set up all my functions but when i run the program it does not display the score of the player despite there being no error messages. Obviously i have programmed in a logic error but i am struggling to debug it.
Player Class header file:
#pragma once 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class player
{
private:
    string playername;
    int hitrate;
    int score;
    bool won;

public:
    void setup_playername(string newplayername)
    {
        playername = newplayername;
    }

    void setup_hitrate(int newhitrate)
    {
        hitrate = newhitrate;
    }

    void setup_score(int newscore)
    {
        score = newscore;
    }

    void setup_won(int newwon)
    {
        won = newwon;
    }
};

C++ File code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int create_player()
{
    int joerate = 71, sidrate = 73;
    int joescore = 501, sidscore = 501;
    bool joewon = false, sidwon = false;

    player joe;

    joe.setup_playername("Joe");
    joe.setup_hitrate(joerate);
    joe.setup_score(joescore);
    joe.setup_won(joewon);

    player sid;

    sid.setup_playername("Sid");
    sid.setup_hitrate(sidrate);
    sid.setup_score(sidscore);
    sid.setup_won(sidwon);

    return joerate, sidrate, joescore, sidscore, joewon, sidwon;
}


string decide_stratagey(int joescore, int sidscore)
{
    string jstrat = "";
    
    if (joescore > 170)
    {
        jstrat = "throwtreble20";
    }

    else if (joescore > 131)
    {
        jstrat = "throw treble";
    }

    else if (joescore > 41)
    {
        jstrat = "throw double";
    }

    else if (joescore == 2)
    {
        jstrat = "throw single";
    }

    else if (joescore == 1)
    {
        jstrat = "bullseye";
    }

    return jstrat;
}

int calcreqdouble(string jstrat, int joescore)
{
    int reqdbl = joescore/2; 

    return reqdbl;
}

int throw_bull(int p) {

    //  Throw for the bull with accuracy p%  (20<p<85)

    int r = rand() % 100;

    if (r < (p - 20))
        return 50;
    else if (r < 85)
        return 25;
    else
        return 1 + rand() % 20;
}


int throw_treble(int d, int p) {

    //  return result of throwing for treble d with accuracy p%  (o<90)

    // Board neighbours ignoring slot zero
    int bd[2][21] = { {0,20,15,17,18,12,13,19,16,14,6,8,9,4,11,10,7,2,1,3,5},
               {0,18,17,19,13,20,10,16,11,12,15,14,5,6,9,2,8,3,4,7,1} };

    int r = rand() % 100;

    if (r < p)
        return 3 * d;
    else if (r < 90)
        return d;
    else if (r < 93)
        return 3 * bd[0][d];
    else if (r < 96)
        return 3 * bd[1][d];
    else if (r < 98)
        return bd[0][d];
    else
        return bd[1][d];
}


int throw_double(int d) {

    //  return result of throwing for double d with accuracy 80%

    // Board neighbours ignoring slot zero
    int bd[2][21] = { {0,20,15,17,18,12,13,19,16,14,6,8,9,4,11,10,7,2,1,3,5},
               {0,18,17,19,13,20,10,16,11,12,15,14,5,6,9,2,8,3,4,7,1} };
    int r = rand() % 100;

    if (r < 80)
        return 2 * d;
    else if (r < 85)
        return 0;
    else if (r < 90)
        return d;
    else if (r < 93)
        return 2 * bd[0][d];
    else if (r < 96)
        return 2 * bd[1][d];
    else if (r < 98)
        return bd[0][d];
    else
        return bd[1][d];
}


int throw_single(int d) {

    //  return result of throwing for single d with accuracy 88% (or 80% for the outer)

    // Board neighbours ignoring slot zero
    int bd[2][21] = { {0,20,15,17,18,12,13,19,16,14,6,8,9,4,11,10,7,2,1,3,5},
               {0,18,17,19,13,20,10,16,11,12,15,14,5,6,9,2,8,3,4,7,1} };
    int r = rand() % 100;

    if (d == 25) {      // outer  80%
        if (r < 80)
            return 25;
        else if (r < 90)
            return 50;
        else
            return 1 + rand() % 20;
    }
    else            // 1 to 20 single
        if (r < 88)
            return d;
        else if (r < 92)
            return bd[0][d];
        else if (r < 96)
            return bd[1][d];
        else if (r < 98)
            return 3 * d;
        else
            return 2 * d;
}


void dartThrowLoop(string jstrat, int joescore,int joerate, int reqdbl, bool joewon)
{
    int randThrow = rand() %(21) + 10;
    while (joewon == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int randThrow = rand() % (21) + 10;
            if (jstrat == "throwtreble20")
            {
                joescore = joescore - throw_treble(20, joerate);
            }

            else if (jstrat == "throw treble")
            {
                joescore = joescore - throw_treble(randThrow, joerate);
            }

            else if (jstrat == "throw single")
            {
                joescore = joescore - throw_single(randThrow);
            }

            else if (jstrat == "bullseye")
            {
                joescore = joescore - throw_bull(randThrow);
            }
        }
    }
} 

int main(string jstrat, int joescore, int joerate, int reqdbl, bool joewon,int sidscore, int sidrate, bool sidwon, int randThrow)
{
    decide_stratagey(int(joescore), int(sidscore));
    calcreqdouble(string(jstrat), int(joescore));
    throw_bull(int(joerate));
    throw_treble(int(randThrow), int(joerate));
    throw_double(int(randThrow));
    throw_single(int(randThrow));
    dartThrowLoop(string(jstrat), int(joescore), int(joerate), int(reqdbl), bool(joewon));

    cout << "score is" << joescore;


    return 0;
}

I have tried adding breakpoints to my code to find out where the problem is but i haven't had any luck in finding where the problem is. I have tried manually inserting a fixed score to the program to see if it was an issue with my dart throw but that didn't work either.

return joerate, sidrate, joescore, sidscore, joewon, sidwon; -- What is this line of code supposed to do?  More to the point -- what C++ book are you using that shows a line of code looking like this, where you have return with a comma separated items being listed as the return value?

decide_stratagey(int(joescore), int(sidscore)); -- Why not simply: decide_stratagey(joescore, sidscore);?  You make the same coding weirdness in other lines in main.

There is some very weird coding here (and no object orientation). This is not a legal way of writing the main function int main(string jstrat, int joescore, int joerate, int reqdbl, bool joewon,int sidscore, int sidrate, bool sidwon, int randThrow). The only two standard ways to write main are int main() and int main(int argc, char** argv). Since your version is nether my guess is that you have a build error, and therefore your program is not running, and that is why you see no output.

Apart from the issue with main, take a good look at your code, there are unused functions and unused parameters all over the place. Remove all of those, it will at least leave less code left to fix. One attribute that programming requires is to be methodical, your approach seems a bit haphazard to me.

The other classic error you have made is to write too much code at once, and now that you have problems you have no idea where the problem is. The productive way to write code is to start with a simple working program, as simple as you can make it, and then gradually increase the complexity until you get to where you want to be. Trying to write too much code too quickly is a typical beginner mistake.

Interesting project. Writing a Monte Carlo simulation for a 501 game of darts is a non-trivial task. The board geometry and aim point are best described in polar coordinates. The location actually hit might also be described in polar coordinates, but in a frame of reference centered at the aim point. Determining where a dart landed, therefore, involves a change of coordinate frames.

Judging by the code in the question, however, the OP is a beginning C++ student. Coding a realistic simulation seems to be beyond his present capabilities. So the question arises: Is this a homework assignment? If so, the OP should edit his question, and provide a more complete description of the assignment. If not, the OP might be best advised to tackle a simpler project for now, and shelve this one for a time when he has gained more experience.

As written, function create_player is a free function, defined outside of any class. In addition, it creates two players, rather than one. Worse yet, player joe and player sid are defined as "local" variables. Both are discarded at the end of function create_player. The code from function create_player should be refactored so that it initializes only one player. It should then become a constructor function for class player, perhaps being coded as: player(std::string const& playername, int hitrate) : playername{ playername }, hitrate{ hitrate }, score{ 501 }, won{ false } {}

main() is a special function. You can't just add parameters to it like that.
It always looks like this
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return 0;
}

To pass parameters to main from the command line you need to iterate through the array argv, which contains argc number of entries.

It always looks like that OR it looks like this int main(), either version is correct.

Judging by the code in the question, the OP is a beginning C++ student. The program in the question contains fundamental errors. The comments (above), identify several of them:

The function signature for main is invalid. (@john)
The return statement in function create_player is not doing what the OP thinks. (@PaulMcKenzie)
Function decide_stratagey is invoked with unnecessary type conversions applied to its arguments. (@PaulMcKenzie)
Function create_player discards the two players it creates. (@tbxfreeware)

There are many other errors, as well. There is nothing wrong with that. We were all beginners at some point.
What follows is a description of the approach I used to tackle this problem. The functions, structs, and classes it describes were developed roughly in the same order as they are presented below.
In the interest of brevity, much of the detail has been omitted. When the workings of a function or class are straightforward, I have left it to the OP to work out the implementation.
Polar coordinates
Mathematical vectors in polar coordinates lie at the heart of a darts 501 simulation. They are used to describe aim points on a dartboard, and also to specifiy "small" targeting errors.
enum class angle_measurement : int { radians, degrees };

class polar
{
    // Implement just enough to run the simulation.
    double r_{};              // radius
    double theta_{};          // internally, angles are stored in radians
    angle_measurement am_{};  // angle units (radians or degrees) used by 
                              //   constructor, function theta(), and operator<<
public:
    // ...

    polar& operator+= (polar const& that) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
    friend polar operator+(polar a, polar const& b) {
        return a += b;
    }
}

polar aim_point = find_aim_point(target);
polar random_error = targeting_error(sigma);
polar hit_point = aim_point + random_error;

target_t and targeting_error
Variable target (above) is a struct that holds one of the numbers from the dartboard (or 0 for bullseye), and an enumeration constant describing the type of score (e.g., single, double, or triple).
enum score_t : int { off_board, single_score, double_score, triple_score };

struct target_t
{
    std::size_t number{};  // [0-20], where 0 == bullseye
    score_t score_type{};
    constexpr target_t(
        std::size_t const number = {},
        score_t const score_type = off_board) noexcept
        : number{ number }
        , score_type{ score_type }
    {}
    std::size_t point_value() const noexcept
    {
        std::size_t n{ number ? number : 25u };
        switch (score_type)
        {
        case off_board: return 0u;
        case single_score: return n;
        case double_score: return n * 2u;
        case triple_score: return n * 3u;
        default: std::unreachable();
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
    std::string to_string() const
    {
        std::string n{ number ? std::to_string(number) : "B" };
        switch (score_type)
        {
        case off_board: return "--";
        case single_score: return n;
        case double_score: return 'D' + n;
        case triple_score: return 'T' + n;
        default: std::unreachable();
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, target_t const& t)
    {
        ost << t.to_string();
        return ost;
    }
};

On each turn, targets are chosen based on current score and dart number (1-3). For scores above 170, the target is always T20 (triple 20). For lower scores, targets are chosen by consulting one of the published checkout charts, such as the one found at Darts Checkout Assistant.
Function choose_target uses lookup tables for scores at or below 170.
target_t target = choose_target(score, dart_number);

Function find_aim_point converts a given target into a specific radius and angle (in polar coordinates). This computation is based on the dimensions of a standard dartboard, which can be found at Dimensions.com.
The inverse function, find_target, converts a given vector (in polar coordinates) into a target_t. For hits that are off the board, it returns target_t{ 0u, off_board }.
target_t hit = find_target(hit_point);

Function targeting_error uses std::normal_distribution to calculate the radius of a "small" error vector. A random angle is selected using std::uniform_real_distribution.
polar targeting_error(double const sigma)
{
    static std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> random_angle(0.0, 360.0);
    static std::normal_distribution<double> random_error;
    using param_type = std::normal_distribution<double>::param_type;
    return polar{ 
        random_error(mt, param_type{ 0.0, sigma }),
        random_angle(mt), 
        angle_measurement::degrees
    };
}

Parameter sigma is the standard deviation used by the normal distribution. It comes from a player's profile, which is stored in class player_t.
class player_t
{
    std::string name_;
    double sigma_{ 1.0 };
public:
    // ...
};

A game is a vector of turns
The functions and classes described above were written first, as part of a "bottom-up" development. Once they were complete, and had passed a small number of tests, development switched to a "top-down" approach, beginning with function main (see below), and class darts_501_simulated_game_t.
Here, there was a bit of back-and-forth, as I knew there would be three main classes (or structs) in the program:

darts_501_simulated_game_t would hold a vector of turns.
turn_t would hold a vector of dart_throws.
dart_throw_t would hold target and hit locations.

I worked on all three in parallel. Class darts_501_simulated_game_t was actually to last of the three that I coded. I had it in mind, however, from the start.
The bust rule is described at Wikipedia.
enum class bust_rule_t : int { standard, northern };

class darts_501_simulated_game_t
{
    player_t player1_, player2_;
    std::size_t points_per_game_{ 501u };
    bust_rule_t bust_rule_{ bust_rule_t::standard };
    std::size_t score1_{}, score2_{};
    std::vector<turn_t> turns;  // <------------ A game is a vector of turns.
public:
    explicit darts_501_simulated_game_t(
        player_t const player1,
        player_t const player2,
        std::size_t const points_per_game = 501u,
        bust_rule_t const bust_rule = bust_rule_t::standard
    )
        : player1_{ std::move(player1) }
        , player2_{ std::move(player2) }
        , points_per_game_{ points_per_game }
        , bust_rule_{ bust_rule }
        , score1_{ points_per_game }
        , score2_{ points_per_game }
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            turns.emplace_back(score1_, player1_.sigma(), bust_rule_);
            score1_ = turns.back().score_after_turn;
            if (turns.back().is_winner())
                break;
            turns.emplace_back(score2_, player2_.sigma(), bust_rule_);
            score2_ = turns.back().score_after_turn;
            if (turns.back().is_winner())
                break;
        }
    }
    auto points_per_game() const noexcept {
        return points_per_game_;
    }
    auto bust_rule() const noexcept {
        return bust_rule_;
    }
    auto score1() const noexcept {
        return score1_;
    }
    auto score2() const noexcept {
        return score2_;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, darts_501_simulated_game_t const& g)
    {
        auto const bust_rule{
            g.bust_rule() == bust_rule_t::standard ? "Standard" : "Northern"
        };
        ost << "Darts " << g.points_per_game() << " Simulation"
            << "\n"
            << "\nPlayer 1: " << g.player1_
            << "\nPlayer 2: " << g.player2_
            << "\nPoints per game: " << g.points_per_game()
            << "\nBust rule: " << bust_rule
            << "\n\n";
        bool toggle{ false };
        int n{};
        for (auto const& turn : g.turns)
        {
            toggle = !toggle;
            ost << ++n << ". " 
                << (toggle ? g.player1_.name() : g.player2_.name())
                << '\n'
                << turn << '\n';
        }
        return ost;
    }
};

A turn is a vector of dart_throws
struct turn_t
{
    std::size_t score_before_turn{}, score_after_turn{};
    std::vector<dart_throw_t> dart_throws;  // <---- A turn is a vector of dart_throws.
public:
    turn_t(
        std::size_t const score_before_turn,
        double const sigma,
        bust_rule_t const bust_rule
        )
        : score_before_turn{ score_before_turn }
        , score_after_turn{ score_before_turn }
    {
        // Precondition established by caller: `score_before_turn > 1u`
        for (int dart_number{ 1 }; dart_number <= 3; ++dart_number)
        {
            dart_throws.emplace_back(
                score_before_turn
                , score_after_turn
                , dart_number
                , sigma
                , bust_rule);
            score_after_turn = dart_throws.back().score_after_throw;
            if (is_winner() || is_bust())
                break;
        }
    }
    bool is_bust() const noexcept {
        return dart_throws.back().is_bust();
    }
    bool is_winner() const noexcept {
        return score_after_turn == zero;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, turn_t const& t)
    {
        for (auto const& d : t.dart_throws)
            ost << d;
        return ost;
    }
};

A dart_throw has a target location and a hit location
enum : std::size_t { zero, one, two, bullseye = zero };

struct dart_throw_t
{
    std::size_t score_before_throw{};
    int dart_number{};
    target_t target;  // <----------------- A dart_throw has a target location 
    target_t hit;     // <----------------- and a hit location.
    std::size_t score_after_throw{};
public:
    dart_throw_t(
        std::size_t const score_before_turn,
        std::size_t const score_before_throw,
        int const dart_number,
        double const sigma,
        bust_rule_t const bust_rule
    )
        : score_before_throw{ score_before_throw }
        , dart_number{ dart_number }
        , target{ choose_target(score_before_throw, dart_number) }
        , hit{ find_target(find_aim_point(target) + targeting_error(sigma)) }
        , score_after_throw { !is_bust() ? score_before_throw - hit.point_value()
            : (bust_rule == bust_rule_t::standard ? score_before_turn : score_before_throw)
        }
    {}
    bool is_bust() const
    {
        auto const pv{ hit.point_value() };
        return pv > score_before_throw 
            || pv + one == score_before_throw
            || pv == score_before_throw 
                && hit.number != bullseye 
                && hit.score_type != double_score;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, dart_throw_t const& d)
    {
        ost << std::setw(3) << d.dart_number 
            << ". Score: " << std::setw(3) << d.score_before_throw
            << "   Target: " << std::setw(3) << d.target
            << "   Hit: " << std::setw(3) << d.hit
            << "   Score: " << d.score_after_throw
            << (d.is_bust() ? " (busted)" : "")
            << (d.hit.score_type == off_board ? " (off board)" : "")
            << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
};

A typical run
int main()
{
    player_t joe{ "Joe", 1.13 }, sid{ "Sid", 1.22 };
    darts_501_simulated_game_t game{ joe, sid };
    std::cout << game << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Darts 501 Simulation

Player 1: Joe (1.13)
Player 2: Sid (1.22)
Points per game: 501
Bust rule: Standard

1. Joe
  1. Score: 501   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 481
  2. Score: 481   Target: T20   Hit:  T5   Score: 466
  3. Score: 466   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 446

2. Sid
  1. Score: 501   Target: T20   Hit:   5   Score: 496
  2. Score: 496   Target: T20   Hit:   5   Score: 491
  3. Score: 491   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 471

3. Joe
  1. Score: 446   Target: T20   Hit:  18   Score: 428
  2. Score: 428   Target: T20   Hit:   5   Score: 423
  3. Score: 423   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 403

4. Sid
  1. Score: 471   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 451
  2. Score: 451   Target: T20   Hit:  T5   Score: 436
  3. Score: 436   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 376

5. Joe
  1. Score: 403   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 383
  2. Score: 383   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 363
  3. Score: 363   Target: T20   Hit:  T5   Score: 348

6. Sid
  1. Score: 376   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 316
  2. Score: 316   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 296
  3. Score: 296   Target: T20   Hit:  T1   Score: 293

7. Joe
  1. Score: 348   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 328
  2. Score: 328   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 308
  3. Score: 308   Target: T20   Hit:   1   Score: 307

8. Sid
  1. Score: 293   Target: T20   Hit:  T1   Score: 290
  2. Score: 290   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 270
  3. Score: 270   Target: T20   Hit:  T5   Score: 255

9. Joe
  1. Score: 307   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 247
  2. Score: 247   Target: T20   Hit:   1   Score: 246
  3. Score: 246   Target: T20   Hit:  T5   Score: 231

10. Sid
  1. Score: 255   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 235
  2. Score: 235   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 215
  3. Score: 215   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 195

11. Joe
  1. Score: 231   Target: T20   Hit:  12   Score: 219
  2. Score: 219   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 159
  3. Score: 159   Target: T19   Hit:  19   Score: 140

12. Sid
  1. Score: 195   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 175
  2. Score: 175   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 115
  3. Score: 115   Target: T19   Hit:   7   Score: 108

13. Joe
  1. Score: 140   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 120
  2. Score: 120   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 60
  3. Score:  60   Target:  20   Hit:  20   Score: 40

14. Sid
  1. Score: 108   Target: T20   Hit:  20   Score: 88
  2. Score:  88   Target: T20   Hit: T20   Score: 28
  3. Score:  28   Target: D14   Hit:  14   Score: 14

15. Joe
  1. Score:  40   Target: D20   Hit:  --   Score: 40 (off board)
  2. Score:  40   Target: D20   Hit:  --   Score: 40 (off board)
  3. Score:  40   Target: D20   Hit:  20   Score: 20

16. Sid
  1. Score:  14   Target:  D7   Hit:  --   Score: 14 (off board)
  2. Score:  14   Target:  D7   Hit:  16   Score: 14 (busted)

17. Joe
  1. Score:  20   Target: D10   Hit:   6   Score: 14
  2. Score:  14   Target:  D7   Hit:   7   Score: 7
  3. Score:   7   Target:   3   Hit:  19   Score: 20 (busted)

18. Sid
  1. Score:  14   Target:  D7   Hit:  D7   Score: 0

